# Disable RigidBody Gravity Temporarily C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, rigid-bodies

Firstly I want to apologise as i understand this will be a very basic request, but I am very new to this world.

i just wish to disable the gravity element of my rigid body for a set amount of time and then enable it until the game resets. if I have understood what ive located on google I need to use a Coroutine but I am having issues doing so.

I attempted to set my gravity element to false initially and use a Wait For Seconds statement to set the gravity to true after so long, but this presented me with errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Going forward, anytime you post a question and talk about errors or code, post them. Any sort of attempt at the issue you're having with specific issues help narrow where the gap of understanding comes from. It helps clarify exactly what your problem is as it gives some form of perspective as the current question is rather general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Rigidbody.useGravity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-useGravity.html) boolean is exactly what you're looking for.

First, obtain a reference to the rigidbody whose gravity you wish to disable. For example via `GetComponent`:

```
private Rigidbody myRb;

public void Start()
{
    myRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
```

Next, create a simple [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html):

```
public IEnumerator GravityDisableRoutine()
{
    myRb.useGravity = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10); //You may change this number of seconds
    myRb.useGravity = true;
}
```

Now, whenever you want to disable the gravity, call:

```
StartCoroutine(GravityDisableRoutine());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody rb = null;
private Coroutine disbaledGravity = null;

public void DisableGravity(float timeToDisable)
{
     rb.useGravity = false;
     if(disabledGravity  != null)
          StopCoroutine(disabledGravity);

    disableGravity = StartCoroutine(EnableGravityAfterDelay(timeToDisable));
}

private IEnumerator EnableGravityAfterDelay(float delay)
{
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
     rb.useGravity = true;
     disableGravity = null;
}
```

Sorry if there are typos - on mobile. General idea is to call the public function with some amount of time where gravity should be disabled. In case a disable gravity event is already occurring, it is cleared and replaced with the new one. After the duration has elapsed after the disable gravity call, gravity is then re-enabled for the object. Once off mobile ill add some resource links to help with understanding the functions used.